# onSaveInstanceState doesn't handle the state

Tags: android, kotlin, onsaveinstancestate

I'm trying to get my edittext1.text while clicking on the getName button after screen flipped but it doesn't work.
**How it should work**

1. adding some text to the et1
2. click setName then tv1 appears
   (tv1.text = et1.text, var "name" = tv1.text)
3. flip the screen
4. click getName (at the et1 have to be value "name" that we put to the
   SaveInstanceState before)

I'm a noobie, hope You can help me! Thanks in advance. <3

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var name: String? = null

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).also { setContentView(it.root) }

            binding.setButton.setOnClickListener { setName() }
            binding.getButton.setOnClickListener { getName() }


        }


        fun getName(){
            binding.et1.setText(name)
        }

        fun setName(){
            binding.tv1.text = binding.et1.text
            name = binding.tv1.text.toString()
        }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

            name = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_NAME, "unknown")
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
        outState.putString(KEY_NAME, name)
    }

    companion object{
        private val KEY_NAME = "NAME"
    }
```

Comment: Flip mean landscape mode!?

Comment: When you rotate the screen the activity is re-created (the `onCreate`method is called). Do your work for getting the name there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another overload of the `onSaveInstanceState` function: the one with with just one parameter: `fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle)`

Your code should look the following:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putString(KEY_NAME, name)
}
```